# Why is my migration status table empty?

Tags: migrations

I wanted to delete all migration modules because of that I use

```
drush config-delete migrate_plus.migration.ID
```

After that, I create a new migration module and enable it with

```
drush en migrate_NAME
```

and rebuild the cache. 
I look at the status table with

```
drush migrate:status
```

but the table shows no migration. If I enable the migration again I get the message "Already enabled". When I try to import something I get the message "No migrations found".
Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that you are mixing up things. By doing

```
drush config-delete migrate_plus.migration.ID
```

you are just deleting migration_plus configuration but you are not disabling the module, it is still enabled. If you really want to disable the module and of course the configuration, you'll have to `drush pm migrate_plus`.

Concerning the "No migrations found" message, your custom module has to define correctly the new migrations (.yml files).